# Premiere Create custom frame size

Tags: video, premiere, editing, cs5

I have downloaded a video from youtube to my laptop. It is 640x360px mp4 format.
I'd like to edit it a little bit with Premiere CS5. How do I create a new project with the same resolution of my video?

It looks like there are a lot of preset but not customizable.

Comment: Thank youuu !!! this helped a lot ! :) i was so desperate..now i can finally make a video :)

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is make a **sequence** with the same frame size as your source file (in Premiere and other NLEs your project doesnt have a specific frame size, as you can have multiple sequences with different frame sizes in one project)

1. Open Premiere and Start a new Project (File > New > Project)
2. Give the project a name and click ok (dont worry about any of the options)
3. In the New Sequence window click Cancel - this will take you straight into the project without making a sequence
4. Import your footage (file > Import)
5. **Create a new Sequence from clip by either:**

   - **Dragging the footage down to the New Sequence icon** (in the project panel) OR 
     [image: New Sequence button]
   - **Right click** on the footage and **select *New Sequence from Clip***
     [image: New Sequence from Clip]

This will create a sequence that matches the attributes of your footage (frame size, frame rate etc)

Comment: You have saved me three hours of endless frustration. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the tab next to 'Load presets'. (Custom settings)
You can only change the frame size when you select editing mode: Desktop.
Now you can change the frame size/ratio to 640x360 or what ever size you want.